# How to setup a many-tiered Rails ActiveRecord many-to-many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

**SOLVED** Please read more at the end of the question and in my answer below.

The accepted question solved the main error.

My own answer gives a description of how to solve the details.

---

Original Question:

I am trying to get a many-to-many relationship to work. I have been reading a lot on stack exchange and in the manual and tutorials for Rails. Until today I thought I had understood what to do, but now I need to retrieve information along the whole chain of models and nothing comes up from the database.

The relations are user <-> membership <-> usergroup <-> accessright <-> function, with membership and accessright as "through"-models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :usergroups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :functions, :through => :usergroups
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :usergroup
end

class Usergroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accessrights
  has_many :functions, :through => :accessrights
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Accessright < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :function
  belongs_to :usergroup
end

class Function < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accessrights
  has_many :usergroups, :through => :accessrights
end
```

I have a user object in my grasp and I want to get the function names for this user object in a list. I try this in a helper module:

```
# Loads the functions the current user via her usergroup has access right to (if any).
def load_user_functions
  if @current_user_functions.nil?
    @current_user_functions = []
    if logged_in?
      @current_user.functions.each do |f|
        @current_user_functions << f.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

From reading the manuals I got the impression that, if I set up the model correctly, I might do something like @current_user.functions.each implicitly.

I put a debugger on the website. I shows me the current user after login, but no information for the functions. They stay empty after login:

```
# Logs in the given user.
def log_in(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  # reset function access rights
  @current_user_functions = nil
  load_user_functions
end

# Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

# Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

Here, the database schema for the tables, as created by my migrations:

```
create_table "accessrights", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "usergroup_id"
  t.integer  "function_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "accessrights", ["usergroup_id", "function_id"], name: "index_accessrights_on_function_id_and_usergroup_id", unique: true, using: :btree

create_table "functions", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "memberships", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "usergroup_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "memberships", ["user_id", "usergroup_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id_and_usergroup_id", unique: true, using: :btree

create_table "usergroups", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "password_digest"
end
```

This is the debugger, that I check the content of the variables with. Maybe the debugger can not handle lists like this?

```
<%= debug(@current_user) if Rails.env.development? %>
<%= debug(@current_user_functions) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

In case there is a meaning to it, the second debugger displays:

```
---
...
```

An extract of my database seed:

```
@function3 = Function.create!(name:  "ViewCreateEditDeleteUsers")

@usergroup3 = Usergroup.create!(name:  "Admin") # gets right to view, create, edit and delete user groups and users

Accessright.create!(function_id:  @function3.id,
                    usergroup_id: @usergroup3.id)

@user = 
    User.create!(username:  "AOphagen",
             email: "ophagen@test.de",
             password: "testing", password_confirmation: "testing", )

Membership.create!(user_id:  @user.id,
                   usergroup_id: @usergroup3.id)
```

After a helpful suggestion by [BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse), I tried the rails console (ouch, should be my favourite tool) and the result is, I have set up the DB correctly:

```
User.find_by(username:"AOphagen").functions.first.name
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'AOphagen' LIMIT 1
Function Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "functions".* FROM "functions" INNER JOIN "accessrights" ON "functions"."id" = "accessrights"."function_id" INNER JOIN "usergroups" ON "accessrights"."usergroup_id" = "usergroups"."id" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "usergroups"."id" = "memberships"."usergroup_id" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "functions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
=> "ViewCreateEditDeleteUsers"
```

---

**SOLVED** The main error was in the database setup. This was solved with the answer I selected as solving my problem (thanks again!). The answer was concise, correct and helpful.

The details of the problem took more time to solve, so I give a detailed answer with how-to below.

I would love to read why my original idea (I knew it was not Ruby-like) did not work - and why the lazy fetch now does, please!

Comment: in your `User` class there is no relation  called `functions`

Comment: you can find function like -> functions = @current_user.user_groups.map{| ug |ug.functions}... this is based on your assosiations in model.

Comment: @Ansar - this is typical N+1 problem here. Resulting list would also be nonquerable

Comment: Yes you are right @BroiSatse but my comment give array of functions, I am just give the answer based on current assosiations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each method you want to call on user you have to create a method. In this case you should use nested `has_many :through` like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :usergroups, through: :memberships
  has_many :functions, through: :usergroups
end
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it!  I'll delete my answer. :)

Comment: Have a look at my edit. This is how it is now. Is that too much? - minus the c&p typo, sorry for that.

It is still not putting anything in the list... ...anything else missing?

Comment: Now, my code is like you said, [BroiSate](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse), but the debugger on my page does not display anything from the functions list. Anything else that might be amiss?

Comment: @AOphagen - does the user actually have any functions? :)

Comment: Try ging it step by step. Firstly check `user.memberships`, then `user.membership.flat_map &:userf groups  (do no tuse this code in your app though -  console use only :P) and so on. Find which part returns incorrect results and find out why. BTW - It is easier to seed test database with FactoryGirl. :)

Comment: Done. The data is accessible from the known user in the console (see my edit above). However, `@current_user_functions` in the debugger is `nil` (as I found out by appending `.first`).

Comment: It's working! There was a problem with how the code snippets were working together in my helper. I'll post the solution shortly plus edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The tiny mean detail problem was my attempt to call a load functions snippet in the `log_in(user)` functions code (see above in my question).

Now I just set the users functions list to `nil` after login:

```
 # Logs in the given user.
def log_in(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  # reset function access rights
  @current_user_functions = nil
end
```

Like with the `@current_user` I wait, until I need the functions for the first time, then load them, if they are still `nil`:

```
# Returns the currently logged-in users function names as list (if any).
def current_user_functions
  if @current_user_functions.nil?
    @current_user_functions = []
    if logged_in?
      @current_user.functions.each do |f|
        @current_user_functions << f.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(I have renamed the function accordingly.)

In the `HTML` I have a branch asking for a certain right:

```
<% if hasRightToViewCreateEditDeleteUsers? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
<% end %>
```

(Still a dummy link there.)

I **presume** it is this that calls the code to load the function names...

```
def hasRightToViewCreateEditDeleteUsers?
  current_user_functions.include?("ViewCreateEditDeleteUsers")
end
```

The debugger now shows the list of function names:

```
---
- ViewCreateEditDeleteUsers
```

And even though my if-clause in the `HTML` is not showing any link yet,

1. I know I will get this to work soon
2. that's irrelevant, since it was not my question in the first place

**Hooray!** Thank you every helpful person here! I will accept [BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse) answer, because he taught me about my main mistake, then helped me debug the details.